# Excel Range.Find and maintaining user selected find options

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto, excel-interop

When automating excel using the Excel Interop API, I can easily do a range search using the method [Range.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find%28v=office.14%29.aspx). I am passing through the LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, and MatchCase options for the Find. This as noted by the MSDN documentation, persists the values passed into this method into the user settings, so the next time that the user opens the find form, the options will be selected which I used in the Range.Find method.

I need to persist the values of the find options before and after I do the programmatic find. So I want to capture the current find options, then do the Range.Find, and then set the find options back to the options that were set before my search. However, I do not see that the find options are publicly accessible. Any ideas on how to get these?

I'm basically looking to retrieve current find option values for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, and MatchCase.

**Update**
The most interesting thing I could find so far is that you can access the Excel Application dialogs - [Dialogs Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dialogs.aspx). So here, I can get access to the FormulaFind dialog, which is slightly different than the Find and Replace dialog, though may lead to some of the properties I'm looking for. I haven't had any luck, but perhaps there's a way to access the properties through this form using reflection. I'll keep trying something with this.

```
// xlDialogFormulaFind, xlDialogFormulaReplace
Excel.Dialog dialog = this.Application.Dialogs.Item[Excel.XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogFormulaFind];
```

Comment: I found a similar thread here, which doesn't solve the question: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=520336, though poses the idea of writing your own find method (which I prefer not to do).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I don't think it's publicly available like you mentioned. Maybe you could create a class called FindOptions and set variables based on your user's input. Then for each time they do a new search, you can create an instance of FindOptions, set the options, and throw it in a stack of "Finds" so you can revert back to any previous search criteria. Is something like this out of the question?

Comment: I see what you're saying, though the issue is in finding the current values. I could create a FindOptions class to persist the values, however, I need to set these values from somewhere. I need to find where I can access the current find options values. How would you set the properties in the FindOptions class is what I'm getting at...?

Comment: Are you referring to creating a find options form where the user can set their defaults?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your users would already have set find options by using Excel's find dialog and setting some options, right? And you want to obtain those settings? Hmm...I really don't think it's possible. The only time I know of that you can get those settings is through a special find (like looking for cells with certain colors, formats, etc.) through the Application.FindFormat object...but that doesn't get you what you need, unfortunately.

Comment: Exactly, we don't want to alter our users last Find Options when we have to do programmatic searches which require changing the options.

Comment: +1, but also taking a quick look at all the methods in the Excel assemblies filtered on "Find", I don't see any method that exposes find settings.

Comment: Same here, I'm googling around to see if there's some other way to access these properties. They have to be persisted somehow, but not publicly through this api.

Comment: Though the settings may be persisted, MS doesn't have to expose it via APIs, which is why you may never find it if they don't.

Comment: That's an interesting piece of code with the Dialogs interface.  Kind of sad there isn't much documentation from what I see. Please post back with what you find on that. I'd like to hear if you found anything useful from that :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if you'd consider this approach, but I'll give a shot here in case it might be helpful.

What I would do is, I'd create a registry key holding the values you wanted to persist. I could then call [RegistryKey.GetValue(valuename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1.aspx) to retrieve values, provided that there's no exceptions thrown.

As long as that registry key stays there, unchanged, and you have enough privilege to access registry key, you should be able to always get the same values.

Wish we could really use application settings here, which would make it easier, but, well, as you might have known, vsto add-in doesn't like it, according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx).

> You cannot use application settings in an unmanaged application that
>   hosts the .NET Framework. Settings will not work in such environments
>   as Visual Studio add-ins, C++ for Microsoft Office, control hosting in
>   Internet Explorer, or Microsoft Outlook add-ins and projects.

Hope this helps.